# Can I use the same fragment multiple times in a single activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity needs to put some custom card fragments in it. These fragments basically look the same, I just need to change some parameter values of each. Now I'm planing to use the same fragment as a 'template' in the page multiple times. But in the fragment's layout xml file there are some fixed item IDs, so if I want to change one of the parameters of the fragment's UI display, I need to use findViewByID() in the fragment's class to set different values of same item ID. Can I do like that?

Comment: yes you can use the same fragment multiple times

Comment: yes you can do like that and use inflater to to inflate the fragment into the view

Comment: yes you can, also you can manipulate the views by using View.GONE, View.VISIBLE, and change the data you put to the bundle.